# SQLException when specifying length along with default value for varchar

Tags: java, spring, h2

I'm trying to initialise an inmemory H2 database with Spring using something like the following statement:

```
===Throws SQLException===

CREATE TABLE config (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  module_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'global',
  ...
);
```

Every time I try to run the project an `SQLException` is thrown saying the syntax is wrong. After quite a bit of experimenting I have noted that when I remove the `DEFAULT` keyword, there is no exception thrown.

```
===This works===

CREATE TABLE config (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  module_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  ...
);
```

What is even more interesting is that when I removed the length on the `VARCHAR` and kept the `DEFAULT` keyword as it is also it worked.

```
===This also works===

CREATE TABLE config (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  module_id VARCHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT 'global',
  ...
);
```

So the question is, is there something preventing both of these being specified together?

Comment: Add the error message

Comment: @Jens The error message was something along the lines of syntax error and showed me the entire query that I've written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a strict reading of the syntax diagram in [documentation for the SQL grammar](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#column_definition)...

[image]

the `default` clause has to come before the `NOT NULL`.

Comment: Any clue to why it worked without specifying the length for `VARCHAR`?

Comment: I have no idea but I would suspect a quirk in the parser.